# How do I know what bit architecture my OS is from Java code?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

I want to determine the bit architecture of my OS i.e whether it is a 32-bit OS or a 64-bit OS using Java code.

I have tried the following:

```
  System.out.printlnSystem.getProperty("os.name"));     //gives OS name -> Windows/Linux/Solaris
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"));   //gives JVM architecture -> amd64
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));   //gives JVM architecture again but just the bit -> 64
```

However none of the above give me the OS architecture. They give the respective output which is mentioned in comments besides the code lines.

How can I determine the OS architecture ?

Comment: `os.arch` tells you the JRE arch your program is running on. Unfortunately there is no direct way to know the os architecture, you'll have to go on with JNI.

Comment: What's wrong with "os.arch"? It already returns amd64?

Comment: @BackSlash - Yes. It gives the JVM architecture. So to find the OS architecture do I have to scan through the registry ? seems like the only option remaining.

Comment: @Crusaderpyro I guess yes. Or maybe you can execute a command which returns the os arch (on linux `uname -m`). But, as JNI, this is OS dependent, so you'll have to get the os name first and then switch to select the proper command to run

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked question is for Windows only and the answers are Windows-specific. The question how to do this cross platform (the much better question imho) remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the environment variable for example for Windows

```
System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to `System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"))`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one line might help you.

```
public class OS {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.out.println("OS name : "+System.getProperty("os.name"));
    //System.out.println("OS arch : "+System.getProperty("os.arch"));
    //System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")); 
    //System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));


    System.getProperties().list(System.out);

 }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));
 gives the JRE architecture.